# make failing in cygwin

Tags: windows, makefile, cygwin

I am trying to run make inside the cygwin environment. I tried it on something simple and it works just fine.

But when I try to run make on the following Makefile, it fails with the following error:

Makefile:220: *** missing target pattern. Stop.

NOTE this is the content of the Makefile at line 220:

```
ahbrom: $(GRLIB)/bin/ahbrom.c
        @if test -r "/mingw/bin/gcc.exe"; then \
          $(CC) $(GRLIB)/bin/ahbrom.c -o ahbrom -lwsock32; \
        else \
          $(CC) $(GRLIB)/bin/ahbrom.c -o ahbrom; \
        fi;
```

Clearly there is a target. I thought that maybe the make program isn't working properly so I changed the installed version from 4.3 to 4.2.1; still nothing changed. What am I missing here.

the Makefile is the following:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XOHS0Sc0UYi-J0HLov4rzb6YfnTUSdn-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: A simple makefile works, a very complex one doesn't. What if you remove half of the complexity? What is [the simplest example that demonstrates the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Check the line endings. They should be LF, not CR+LF. I always use a TAB after the ':' following a target. Some make's accept any whitespace there.